# Notification Extension - GNOME Shell

Tags: gnome, extension

On Linux Mint 12, there's a extension for "important" notifications to be put in the panel.  ie. DropBox would be put up in the panel.

Is there an extension for Ubuntu that does that?  I have searched the GNOME repos and other third party ppas and I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: You can just copy the Mint extension to Ubuntu... it's the same Gnome SHell FYI...

Comment: But how?  I haven't even found it online.  The only ones i find are MGSE Windowlist and menu...

Answer (score 2):

WebUpd8 do try their best to adapt most important Gnome-Shell extensions for Ubuntu, and have already put three of MGSE extensions in their repository. Unfortunately, the one you want is not there yet.

So, you may want to get it from their GitHub branch.

1) Install git:

```
sudo apt-get git
```

2) Create a folder where you want to put all Git repositories

3) cd to that folder and use git to create a clone:

```
git clone https://github.com/linuxmint/MGSE.git
```

Later to update use

```
git pull
```

4) When everything is done, it will create a separate folder MGSE. So, cd to that folder. You will see a bunch of folders containing an extension each. There is a file called test to install all of them at once, and there is also one file test in each folder to install one particular extension. Run either one depending on what you want.

I do not recommend installing all their extensions at once. To avoid conflicts in your system and keep it stable, install only those not available, or at least, not installed through other repositories such as WebUpd8 Gnome3 PPA.

Answer (score 2):

GNOME Shell Classic Systray extension is basically the same as the Mint Notifications extension, except it doesn't move the clock to the right. Install it in Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-classic-systray
```

More info @ [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/try-new-mint-gnome-shell-extensions.html)

There's also an extension that lets you manually specify which icons to display on the top bar, called [Icon Manager](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/move-icons-from-message-tray-to-top.html), but it's not available in a PPA.